# How should we expand common duplicate targets to be more acceptable to the folks asking duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, edits, duplicate-questions, canonical

#### Summary

A user did research, couldn't find an answer, and asks a question. The new question is closed as a duplicate, but he can't understand the answer provided on the original. How should we alter the answer(s) on the target question such that they'll satisfy those asking duplicates?

#### Background

Recently a user came into chat and brought up a valid point. He was upset his question was marked as duplicate even though the answers on the non-duplicate question didn't fix his problem. [This was the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460955/menustrip-selected-color) is marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260303/how-to-change-menu-hover-color)(note there will likely be further edits to the questions by the time I post this). He was correct. The question he asked was NOT answered by the duplicate one. Although the answers were similar. It's a classic case of "Because you know the answer it looks obvious but to those who don't..."

I played devils advocate and found it interesting. Someone said "knowing the correct properties is certainly useful" and I countered with "That's the thing! If you know the correct properties you wouldn't be on the question in the first place."

#### What we tried

BradleyDotNET did his best to resolve this by editing the accepted answer on the target question to add a link to additional documentation on the properties being referenced. But OP wasn't satisfied because it wasn't obvious to him that the link answered his question either. Examining this from the user's point of view, I can see how the link could easily be ignored as not relevant or just not seen.

So, **what is a good strategy for including more information on the subject so that very similar questions can be answered by one main answer?**

Comment: @rene Oh, I didn't mean to phrase it like this was a "user causing hell in chat" problem. More like "User causing hell had valid point. How do fix"

Comment: Feels like you're burying the lede here; state the problem you're trying to solve up front. Right now I'm not clear on whether this is an interpersonal issue, an issue with updating answers to old questions, or overzealous marking of duplicates...

Comment: @Shog9 If I read it correctly, the question is about how to generalize a good dupe-target to include 99% duplicate questions, so people accept the duplicate mark on such questions.

Comment: That's a good question, @Bradley - is that really what you're asking here, Griffin?

Comment: I happened to see the chat messages.  The OP had to be told the name of the class and somebody reversed ColorTable to TableColor.  Causing a train of chat messages where the OP kept complaining that Google did not produce any results.  "User did research",  well, not exactly.  The duplicate has a somewhat clumsy question title by using the word "hover", the answer solves his problem.

Comment: @HansPassant This is more related to what happened *after* that, but that was the start of it.

Comment: @Shog9 Edited TLDR to make more clear. Yes it is.

Comment: @HansPassant This was a ... less than ideal example but I know it happens quite often.

Comment: Well, it is an ideal example of leading a horse to water but him refusing to drink it.  It happens quite often.

Comment: See my revisions, @Griffin.

Comment: @Shog9 You should take a look at revision [13](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31460955/revisions), you might need to step in and lock the question.

Comment: Handled, @Daedalus.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks, kind of forgot there were other methods.

Comment: @Shog9 Went home sorry I was MIA. Texting and driving is bad for my health. But yes. That makes it more clear.

Answer (score 11):

It depends a little bit on the duplicate.

If the duplicate is recognized by the community as a canonical question (and therefore the most appropriate target) for many similar questions, you update the canonical answer(s) and/or question to reflect the slightly different angle/common phrasing/synonyms etc. In other words: you edit the canonical to be a perfect fit.

If the duplicate isn't a canonical post and the difference is just in the terms/wording/syntax and not in context, leaving a comment on the answer is the best way. That gives that OP the opportunity to judge if the answer applies to the case under scrutiny and they will update their answer when they see fit.

If that doesn't fly or the context is clearly different it is better to gather information and facts so the OP can improve the question.  The OP needs to underpin the specific nature and/or difference to possible duplicates. Contacting users in chat could be one way of getting those points cleared, if done in a respectful way.

It remains the responsibility of the OP to convince the users with reopen votes that the question was wrongly closed.

If discussion in chat, editing and going through the reopen-queue doesn't work,  a meta post tagged [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) could be asked to see if more eyes can help resolve the issue or the meta effect kicks-in.

<sup>I didn't visit the questions linked to, nor did I check the chat transcript for what has happened there</sup>

Comment: *"It remains the responsibility of the OP to convince the users with reopen votes that the question was wrongly closed."* nice touch and very much agree :)

Comment: Note that I've edited the question slightly to reflect clarifications left in comments.

Comment: In this case, the only difference between the question was having the answers differ at "instead of overriding properties A and B, override properties X and Y" (of the same class). I think that feels similar to your third case, and yet the answer is *so similar* that it still feels like a duplicate to me.

Comment: I refuse to visit those questions but I can see why someone doesn't accept a duplicate that has an answer that says to override properties that they have never seen or used yet...

Comment: @rene As can I, and I don't blame you for not wanting to visit. The question I would pose is how can handle this better? Just reword the duplicate to ask which properties to use (instead of the more general 99% duplicate post)?

Comment: I would only take that effort if the other question/answer is perfect, possible a duplicate target more often  and all parties agree, specially the ones on the target post(s). If not I would simply help the OP to get some edits in so it makes a chance on being re-opened and if that doesn't work, move along.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it sounds like the user did the right thing by going to chat. When applicable, that is a much better way to handle disagreements than bringing it to meta. With chat, you can have experienced users in that language/framework/whatever that can help decide if it is a dupe and if so explain why. If they don't believe it is, then they can rally to reopen the question.

> How do we make answers on base questions (those that other questions will be marked as duplicates of) include answers to their slightly varying but still declared duplicate counterparts?

If the question is a dupe then adding an answer to the target dupe with a different approach would be the way to go. But it sounds like it isn't really a duplicate.

The original says "How to change the Hover"

whereas the post we are discussing says "By "selected" i mean you clicked on the menu option. NOT hover."

I'm not a C# expert but it sounds like they are two different things. In this case, the appropriate action is for knowledgeable folks in that area to vote to reopen.

Comment: Note that I've edited the question slightly to reflect clarifications left in comments.

Comment: Please note that when going to chat, it is advisable to listen and seriously consider what said experienced users are trying to tell you :)

Comment: @codeMagic They aren't the same things. But they're similar enough that they could easily be "merged" so that one answer satisfies both.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I certainly agree with that. If you are going into a chat, you need to be respectful, read the room rules, and try to have a polite discussion. It wasn't apparent to me that this wasn't the case from reading the post.

Comment: @Griffin that may be. Those of you who are experts/experienced in the tag would know better than I. If that is the case then posting an answer, as I said in my answer would probably be the way to go. Still, I can see how these could easily be two separate questions. Then link to each other as a for further information type thing. But the questions seem different enough to me to not be duplicates.

Comment: @codeReview Exactly. A linking /merger system would be an effective tool in helping people on the site

Comment: @Griffin that may not be a terrible suggestion. If you can formulate something then you can post a feature-request. However, that's better suited on its own post. There already is a merger type of system but I'm not really sure this fits for that

Comment: @codeMagic If you read the deleted answer, you can get the idea of how the chat went :(

Comment: @BradleyDotNET that may have just confused me more ;) But I do now know that you have a loyal padawan and I can imagine how the chat might have went now. I *almost* want to dig up the chat history now :)

Comment: @codeMagic I don't know, looks like he switched to the OP. I'll get over it :)